# What is the purpose of Dragon Shouts level 2 and 3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've tried using [Ice Form shout](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Form) level 2 (Slen) but I didn't notice any difference compared to level 1 (Iiz). Same goes for throw voice - it however has a lower cooldown, but I couldn't notice anything else. Can someone please explain? Why would I want to be spending Dragon Souls on shouts level 2 and 3?

Comment: throw voice levels 2 & 3 decreases the cooldown so you can use it more often if I recall.  Its one of the few that works differently from the other level 2-3 shouts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Higher level shouts usually add more damage, longer effect durations, or more effects at the cost of higher cooldown.  (more info [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts))

For [ice form](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ice_Form) specifically, it increases the amount of time spent frozen and increases the recharge time.

```
              Effects                        Recharge
Iiz     Paralysis and 2 damage/s for 15 s   60
Slen    Paralysis and 2 damage/s for 30 s   90
Nus     Paralysis and 2 damage/s for 60 s   120
```

Each shout is different. Some are absolutely awesome at level 3 and lack luster at level 1. Look at [Soul Tear](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Tear) for example.

```
               Effects  Recharge
Rii     Slight push     5
Vaaz    Slight push     5
Zol     Soul Trap for 2 secs on enemy, drain health 300 pts and reanimate body upon death for 1 minute.
```

Answer (score 5):

They higher the level of the shout means the more damage it does with a longer cooldown , for instance when you first learn ' Fus ' of the 'fus-ro-dah' it is weak but once all levels / words are unlocked of it you've gone from tickling bandits to throwing goats off a mountain , hope this helps but Words/levels = upgrades to the shout! :)

Comment: There are goats in this game?

Comment: Yes , You get goat hide them them which makes leathers :)

Comment: I wish I could throw goats off mountains... but I took an arrow to the knee :(

Answer (score 2):

Level 2 and 3 shouts become stronger or better in one way or another, depending on the the specific shout. You can read how different shouts get upgraded with levels at [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts#Available_Dragon_Shouts). For exmaple, [Ice Form](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ice_Form) paralyzes and applies a DOT effect on the target for 15 seconds at the 1st level, for 30 seconds at the 2nd level, and 60 seconds at the 3rd level; while [Throw Voice](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Throw_Voice) simply reduces the cooldown with extra levels.